# Constructing RestTemplates with Spring @Configuration

Tags: java, spring

Say I have some application-wide configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public HttpClient anHttpClient() {
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClientConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        // set some properties
        // ...
        return HttpClientBuilder.create().setConnectionManager(poolingHttpClientConnectionManager).build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public ClientHttpRequestInterceptor aRequestInterceptor() {
        ....
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public ClientHttpRequestInterceptor anotherRequestInterceptor() {
        ....
    }
}
```

Then I have some particular service that looks like:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    private final RestTemplate myParticularRestTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public MyService(RestTemplate myParticularRestTemplate) {
         this.myParticularRestTemplate = myParticularRestTemplate;
    }

    /***
    * Some incredible application logic
    ***/

    @Configuration
    public static class Config {

        private int SOME_READ_TIMEOUT;
        private int SOME_CONNECT_TIMEOUT;

        @Bean
        public RestTemplate myParticularRestTemplate(HttpClient anHttpClient, List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors) {
            HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(anHttpClient);
            clientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(SOME_READ_TIMEOUT);
            clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(SOME_CONNECT_TIMEOUT);

            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);
            restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);

            return restTemplate;
        }
    }
}
```

I want the interceptors to be injected into `RestTemplate`s system-wide, but, as it is, because I've got to access nested objects of the `RestTemplate` to set particular configuration, I need to instantiate the `RestTemplate` myself -- at least as I understand it.

Is there a nicer way to address this that doesn't require configuration for specific `RestTemplate`s to know about the `List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor>`?